# GeeksforGeeks rotate array - counter clockwise by d times - getting wrong result

Tags: python

I am trying to solve GeeksforGeeks problem [Rotate Array](https://practice.geeksforgeeks.org/problems/rotate-array-by-n-elements-1587115621/1#):

> Given an unsorted array `arr[]` of size `N`. Rotate the array to the left (counter-clockwise direction) by `D` steps, where `D` is a positive integer.

My code produces the wrong result for the example input:

- Input: `A=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`, `D=2`
- Result: `A=[3, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5]`
- Expected: `A=[3, 4, 5, 1, 2]`

Here is my code. Where did I go wrong?

```
class Solution:
    #Function to rotate an array by d elements in counter-clockwise direction. 
    def rotateArr(self,A,D,N):
        j=0
        for i in range(0,D):
            a=A[j-1]
            for j in range(1,len(A)):
                A[j-1]=A[j]
            A.append(a)
        return A
```

Comment: *why this code is not working...?* Saying it three time will not make the code work

Comment: It would be good to give an example of what your expected output is as well as show/explain what it is doing wrong and what you have tried to approach the problem.

Answer (score 0):

These are some issues:

- Your code makes the list longer each time `append` is executed
- In the next iterations of the outer loop, `j` will be where it left of in the previous iteration, which always is `len(A) - 1`.
- It is not asked to *return* anything. The given list will be tested, not the returned value.
- Instead of moving values one position at a time, it will be more efficient to calculate what the final position of a value will be, and move it there.
- When D is much larger than N, it doesn't make sense to keep rotating that many times. First clip D so it is smaller than N.
- This code has a time complexity of O(DN), which is not very nice when D gets large. This can be done with O(N) time complexity, when above two points are taken into account.

Proposed solution:

```
    def rotateArr(self,A,D,N):
        D = D % N
        A[:] = A[D:] + A[:D]
```

Answer (score 0):

The list A is updated whenever you assign a value.
A new list should be needed to keep the rotated value.

```
class Solution:
    #Function to rotate an array by d elements in counter-clockwise direction. 
    def rotateArr(self,A,D,N):
        #j=0 --> don't need
        for i in range(0,D):
            B =[]
            a = A[0]   #A[j-1]
            for j in range(1,len(A)):
                B.append(A[j]) # A[j-1]=A[j]
            #print(B)
            B.append(a)
            A = B
        return B # A    
##        return A[1:]+A[0:1]
#{ 
#  Driver Code Starts
#Initial Template for Python 3

import math
def main():
    T=int(input())

    while(T>0):
##        nd=[int(x) for x in input().strip().split()]
##        N=nd[0]
##        D=nd[1]
        # split() would be enough to remove white space
        N, D = [ int(x) for x in input().split()]
        A=[int(x) for x in input().split()]
        ob=Solution()
        A = ob.rotateArr(A,D,N)  # Need to assign the result to A
        
        for i in A:
            print(i,end=" ")
            
        print()
       
        T-=1
```

Following code might be a simplified version.

```
def rotateArr(A,D):
    for i in range(0,D):
        A = A[1:]+A[0:1]
    return A   

def main():

    for i in range(int(input())):
        N, D = [ int(x) for x in input().split() ]           
                   
        A=[int(x) for x in input().split()][:N]
        if len(A) < N : print('input len < N'); break;
        
        print( *rotateArr(A,D) )

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

Just define a function instead of class method, which is simplified with slicing. List slicing makes a new list.

Answer (score 0):

in javascript, we can try this

```
let arr = [1,2,3,4,9]
let n = 5, D= 2

rotateArray= (arr, size, rotate) =>{
    return arr.slice(rotate, size).concat(arr.slice(0, rotate));
}
console.log(rotateArray(arr, n, D))
```

Answer (score -1):

There are multiple problems here. You first create a variable j and set it to zero and then you redefine j inside the for loop. In python, variables retain their values when the for loop is done and so you might want to use another variable for the for loop. But it doesn't make sense that you would define a as A[j-1] because when you shift all your elements to the left in the second for loop, it is A[0] which is lost and so you might want to change A[j-1] to A[0] or A[k] where k is always zero. After the second for loop, you append instead of replacing the last element of the array with a. This is why your result is longer than your initial array. I made a few changes to your original code. Here you go:

```
def rotateArr(A,D,N):
    # Change j to k. An integer with a constant value of 0
    k = 0
    for i in range(0,D):
        a=A[k] # Or just make a = A[0] for simplicity
        for j in range(1, len(A)):
            A[j-1]=A[j]
        # Replace last term with first element of former list
        A[-1] = a
    return A
```

Alternatively, you can use this simpler code I wrote myself:

```
def rotate(nums, D, length): # nums = A, D = D, length = N
    # So that if D > length, only the net movement will be done
    D = D % length

    # For D times, remove first element and put it at the back
    for times in range(D):
        item = nums.pop(0)
        nums.append(item)
    return nums
```

Comment: why was this disliked? i'm confused ;(